# If $x$ is isolated in $E \subset X$, then it is a limit point of $E^c$

Tags: general-topology

This is a statement that seems true, but I can't prove it!

> If $x$ is isolated in $E \subset X$, $X$ a metric space, then it is a
>   limit point of $E^c$.

So far my thinking goes like this:

If $x$ is isolated in $E$, then $x \in E$, and then there exists some neighborhood $N_x(r)$ for $x$ such that $N_x(r) \cap E = \{x\}$

Let $N$ be any neighborhood of $x$, I want to show there is some point of $E^c$ in $N$.

But here, I stop because I can't turn the first sentence into the existence of a point outside $E$. In particular, if $E=X$, then the compliment is empty, so how could I show that there always is a point there?

Or am I wrong and the statement is not true? Then can I see a counter-example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not true if $x$ is isolated in $X$.

Comment: (I'm assuming $E^c$ is the complement, not the closure.)

Comment: Consider a 1-point space $X=E=\{x\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true if $x$ is isolated in $X$. You have, specifically:

> If $x$ is isolated in $E$, then ($x$ is isolated in $X$ if and only if $x$ is not a limit point of $E^c$.)

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $x$ is isolated in $E$ and not a limit point of $E^c$, then there is a neighborhood $N_1$ of $x$ which contains no point of $E\setminus \{x\}$ and a neighborhood $N_2$ of $x$ which contains no point of $E^c$.

And hence $N_1\cap N_2=\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ which contains no other point of $X$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $x$ is an isolated point of $X$, then $\{x\}$ is an open set of $X$, and is not a limit point of $E^c$ because $\{x\}$ does not contain any point of $E^c$.

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me why$N_2$ exists? If its not a limit point of $E^c$, shouldn't there exist a $N_2$ which contains no point of $E^c$? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yep, I mangled my argument. Fixed.

Comment: Now it looks perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the metric space $X$ equipped with discrete topology.

In that case every $x\in E$ is isolated in $E$ since $\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

But limit points of sets do not even exist in the discrete case.

Comment: Isn't the sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n=x$ for all $n$ a sequence converging to $x$? Certainly, there are limit points, since $X$ is a metric space, and since $X$ is complete. Wouldn't every point of every set be a limit point, since every subset is complete?

Comment: @Chickenmancer   $x$ is by definition a limit point of set $E$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of $E$ different from $x$. That does not occur in the discrete case. We are dealing with limit points of sets. Not of sequences.

Comment: In a metric space, isn't a point a limit point precisely when there exists a sequence converging to it?

Comment: @Chickenmancer Then is a limit (or limit point) of a **sequence**.Not necessarily of a set.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the case of a discrete space, $E$ will not have a limit point, because the definition of a limit point of $E$ would require that any open ball about $x$ would possess some point other than just $x$ itself, and since any ball of radius less than $1$ would be precisely $x,$ then $x$ is not a limit point.

Comment: @Chickenmancer Exactly!